# If a column in sharepoint list equals a paticular string then you must enter data in another column in the list

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to enter a query in the calculated column that forces a user to enter data in another column of a list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a warning message in the calculated column (visible after data is saved, not in the new item form), but **out-of-the-box SharePoint doesn't support columns that are dynamically required or optional**.